# What properties should a typeface or font for children's signage have while still being playful?

Tags: typography, typefaces

I am looking for a typeface for use with children's signage (don't say Comic sans). I'm looking for something playful yet legible. By children, I mean elementary school age (and younger).

What a re properties in typefaces I should look for to find such a typface? Actual typeface suggestions are welcome, too.

Comment: This question is a little like askin "what kind of pencil should i use for drawing" In a sense.. It doesnt matter that much as you can draw with anything that leaves a mark really. So i guess im saying that it just depends on how you feel like. There could be hundreds of good fonts out there.

Comment: I'm sure there are hundreds of good typefaces for this task. But I'm not familiar many faces other than the few I use with my word processor. Yes, you can draw with anything that leaves a mark but a novice still needs guidance as to the best tools for certain tasks.

Comment: Its not specific i know but rather than telling you specific fonts, i would say look up different ones in places like http://www.dafont.com/ for example. And searchfreefonts like laurem ipsum linked

Comment: Hi Ken, I edited your question to make it more objectively answerable. If you really disagree with my edit, feel free to roll it back!

Answer (score 3):

I'm fond of [Lemonade](http://www.searchfreefonts.com/font/lemonade.htm). Surprisingly readable for all that it's "cutesy."

Answer (score 2):

If Lemonade won't work for you, try VAG Rounded, Adera (especially Adera Display) or even Arial Rounded. They all work well in this context because the letterforms are standard but friendly, and you can always add "playful" using colors, puffy bevels, baseline shifts and character rotations.

Comment: Also, handwritten fonts are often the type ( much like lemonade )

Comment: +1. I myself have a preference for rounded fonts (over handwritten) fonts for this kind of purpose

Answer (score 2):

The kind of usage you have will determine how much playfulness you'll be able to get away with.

If it's short text, you can try something more fun, for example:

[JollyGood Sans](http://www.jollygoodfonts.com/)
(full disclosure: I designed it)

[Dr Agu Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rastvortsev/dr-agu-sans/?refby=pixilate)

[Billy](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sparkytype/billy/?refby=pixilate)

If you need something more serious I can recommend:

[Mikado](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hvdfonts/mikado/?refby=pixilate)

[Linotte](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jcfonts/linotte/?refby=pixilate)

[Tide Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/kyle-wayne-benson/tide-sans/?refby=pixilate)

Answer (score 1):

I like century gothic" because it has the simple a and g shapes that children are taught.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get away from faux handwritten typefaces but want something that looks child (and presumably parent) friendly you could try a softer looking typeface with warm overtones like:

- [ITC Gorilla](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/itc-gorilla/)
- [Cooper Black](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=44470)
- [Souvenir](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/itc-souvenir/)